# MODX Evolution upgrade: how can I identify snippet/plugin changes to be kept?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have a website, not developed by me, running MODX Evolution 1.0.15. I would like to bring this up to date, not least for security reasons. However the upgrade documentation starts with 'If you have modified any of the default snippets or plugins...' at which point I get stuck because I do not know how to tell whether the original developer made such modifications or not. I have googled this without success. How can I identify such changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Manager Action reports, and if that has been cleared, check the files' dates. If they have been changed, their dates won't match the dates of all of the other files.

For future reference, take a little time to make notes of anything along those lines that you may do, so that you or other developers will know what you've done.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the Actions are only logged back to a date 2 years after initial go-live, and the file dates are all set to the date on which the developer moved the whole lot across to the cpanel hosting where it now resides. I will try locating/downloading a clean copy of the release I have, and then doing a file level comparison. Seems to me this would be a useful utility for someone to write - maybe I should have a go sometime.